# C 2d dynamic array in memory

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create 2d dynamic array.

**My Code**

```
char **tab;
tab = malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(char *));
printf("%p\n", tab);
tab++;
printf("%p\n", tab);
tab++;
printf("%p\n", tab);
return  0;
```

It gives me following Output.

```
8
0xfcd010
0xfcd018
0xfcd020
```

My question is why difference between 2nd and 3rd element is only `2`?

Comment: It is not - that is hexadecimal and the difference is 8.

Comment: ... `8 9 A B C D E F 0`....

Comment: Please always give [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the relationship between the title of question and actual question?

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are hexadecimal

> 0x20 - 0x18 = 8